# Periodic Killing spinor on $S^1$?

Tags: spinors

In Cartesian coordinates on $R^2$ we have a constant two component Killing spinor $\epsilon_0$. If we use polar coordinates

$x = R \cos t$

$y = R \sin t$

we have the vielbein

$e^R = dR$

$e^t = R dt$

This vielbein is related to the Cartesian vielbein

$E^x = dx = \cos t dR - R \sin t dt$

$E^y = dy = \sin t dR + R \cos t dt$

by the transition matrix

$g = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos t & \sin t\\
-\sin t & \cos t
\end{array}\right)$

in the vector representation of the local $SO(2)$ tangent space group. In the spinor representation of this $SO(2)$, this transition matrix is represented as

$g = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i t/2} & 0\\
0 & e^{-i t/2}
\end{array}\right)$

and the constant Killing spinor is mapped into

$\epsilon = g^{-1} \epsilon_0$

that satisfies the Killing spinor equation

$\partial_t \epsilon = \frac{i}{2} \sigma_3 \epsilon$

on $S^1$. The solution is anti-periodic

$\epsilon(t+2\pi) = - \epsilon(t)$

My question is how to explicitly construct the Killing spinor on $S^1$ that corresponds to the periodic spin structure

$\epsilon(t+2\pi) = + \epsilon(t)$

which should be the one that generalizes to $S^n$ for $n>1$ where we only have one spin structure (the periodic one).